# Javafx TextField memory issues

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, java-memory-leaks

I could use some help debugging a memory (leak?) issue. I've made a simple example below. There's some kind of bug in Javafx related to TextFields. The below code adds 2000 TextFields to a FlowPane within a ScrollPane. According to task manager, Java uses ~420mb at this point.

Pressing the add button adds another 2000 TextFields every time it is pressed. Each time adds maybe 80-200 mb (somehow it's not always the same amount of memory??). The remove button removes the TextFields, but memory is never freed. This is with Java jdk 9 where - as far as I understand things - the GC should free up memory that is no longer in use and return it to the OS. Changing TextFields into Texts solves the issue, takes far less memory and actually returns it to the OS when appropriate, but I would prefer to have TextFields. Does anyone know how to fix/work around this? :-)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class main extends Application
{
    private ScrollPane scroll;
    private FlowPane pane;
    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            this.stage=stage;
            pane = new FlowPane();
            Button b1 = new Button("Add 2000");
            Button b = new Button("Remove 2000");

            b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    addTextFields();

                }});        
            b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        removeTextFields();
                        System.gc();

            }});
            pane.getChildren().add(b);
            pane.getChildren().add(b1);



            scroll = new ScrollPane();



            scroll.setContent(pane);


            addTextFields();

            scene = new Scene(scroll,800,600);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void addTextFields()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            //Text text = new Text("T " + i);
            TextField textField = new TextField("T "+i);

            this.pane.getChildren().add(textField); 
        }
    }

    private void removeTextFields()
    {
        for(int i=2001; i>1; i--)
        {       
        //  Text f = (Text) this.pane.getChildren().get(i);
            TextField f = (TextField) this.pane.getChildren().get(i);

            this.pane.getChildren().remove(f);          
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: strip it down to barest essentials that demonstrate the problem --- please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - nobody wants to wade through tons of code plus it's part of your job of debugging anyway ;)

Comment: I've removed all code and added only the TextField part of the problem for now. Beginning to think this really is a bug in JavaFx's textFields.

Comment: hmm ... looks okay to me: running in visualVm (which looks like not being able to monitor much more than heap space for java9), the used heap is increased when adding (up to the max heap) and decreased when removing ...

Comment: How much memory is it using for you? Is it much more than when you use Texts?

Comment: Also, is memory given back to the OS for you?

Comment: didn't test Text (not not going to ;) - guess so, why shouldn't it when it disappears from used/heap? Anyway, why would you need so many TextFields? They do need lots of memory, and that's why there are virtualized controls like Listview/TableView

Comment: For me the used heap size increases and so does the heap size. But even though the used heap size does decrease, the normal heap size is never decreased even though the above code calls the GC directly. Only when I press the GC button within VisualVM does the heap size actually decrease. Don't get it. :-)

As to why I need so many TextFields - well, perhaps I don't. I'm a noob at JavaFx. Will look into ListViews/TableViews. But this seemed like an easy, straightforward implementation with basic Javafx components. I'm surprised to see a simple TextField causing this kind of problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's perfectly normal for java 9 to e.g. keep taking up over a GB in heap space memory with only a basic stage, scrollpane and an emptied flowpane in play (that **used to** contain several thousand TextFields). The memory is never released back to the OS unless forced within VisualVM even after calling the GC explicitly from code.

This GC behaviour doesn't make any sense to me, particularly on a poor man's system with only 4 gb of ram that is already mostly in use before I run Java, but I'll work around it by either using Texts or using a TableView.